# How to use the 'test' command in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I use the CLI command to run a DAG with parameters : `airflow dags test first_dag --conf '{"my_parametr":["2023-12-13","ANY"]}'`

The structure of my code looks like this:

```
def main(**kwargs) -> None:

    my_parametr = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('my_parametr')
    
    print(my_parametr)

task_run_cmd = PythonOperator(task_id='main',
                              python_callable=main,
                              provide_context=True,
                              dag=dag,
                             )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

I expected that after calling the DAG in the CLI, the parameters would be printed: :`["2023-12-13","ANY"]`
Instead, I received a message that the DAG has been executed. I suspect that the DAG did not run.
Please tell me what could be the reason. airflow 2.8.0

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'roman',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 2, 6),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': 0,
}

dag = DAG(
    'first_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Your DAG description',
    schedule_interval='0 4 * * *',
)
```

Comment: can you try to edit the DAG 
schedule_interval=None, 
and run the test with the --show-dagrun option suggested by the docs below:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html

Comment: What's the question? What reason would you want to know?